# I can't bind image source in v-for loop | vue.js, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

I try to bind image source in my v-for loop. My array is filled by functions and isn't static.

My code looks that:

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="match in matches" class="card">
      <img :src="match.avatar" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And

```
created() {
ipcRenderer.send('get:all:champions')
ipcRenderer.send('summoner:recent:matches:request')
ipcRenderer.on('summoner:recent:matches:response', (event, matches) => {
  matches.splice(-15, 15) // -15, 15

  this.matches = matches

  for (let match in matches) {
    ipcRenderer.send('matches:champion:avatar:request', { element: match, championId: matches[match].champion })
  }

  ipcRenderer.on('matches:champion:avatar:response', (event, data) => {
    this.matches[data.element].avatar = data.avatar
  })
})
}
```

I get error in console and any pic doesn't show.
Error:

```
(node:9696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 42): Error: Request failed with status code 429
```

I hope you can help me =)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Comment: I don't understand where is problem 'cause when I'm using static image files I have still the same error.

Comment: server side problem